# fill a polygon with its four vertix

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have 4 points that identify a polygon into an image, this polygon is more or less a rectangle. I want to fill this polygon.
I have been trying `fillConvexPoly` but it fill a triangle with 3 of these points. Why?

```
img = cv2.imread('image_4.png')
points = [[ 903  192]
          [ 880  390]
          [1230  152]
          [1157  433]]
cv2.fillConvexPoly(img, points, 0, 16)
```

Also, I have been trying `drawContours` but I have no contours. Are there any functions that create a line pass through all this points creating a polygon that look likes a rectangle?

So, how can I solve it?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I tried yesterday but it didn't work. I was wrong to do this swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code.

Test this (see order of the points):

```
img = np.ones([600, 1500], np.uint8) * 255
points = np.array([[903, 192], [880, 390], [1157, 433], [1230, 152]], np.int64)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(img, points, 0, cv2.LINE_8)
# plt.imshow(img)
# cv2.imwrite('polygon.jpeg', img)
```

It should result in this image:
[image]

**Try read you image as grayscale:**

```
img = cv2.imread('image_4.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```